# Importing Timestamps into Pandas dataframe, and calculating total time worked

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

Okay, I've been working on this for hours now, and tried searching multiple other answers, but can't seem to find exactly what I need.  I have a dataframe of employees, who have a variable number of clock in and clock out times on a *.csv file that I'm importing into a Pandas dataframe.  For instance:

| Name | In | Out | In | Out | In | Out | In | Out | In | Out |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | 06/12/2023 12:05:00 p.m. | 06/12/2023 12:15:00 p.m. |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Steve | 06/12/2023 1:00:00 p.m. | 06/12/2023 5:00:00 p.m. | 06/13/2023 09:00:00 a.m. | 06/13/2023: 5:00:00 p.m. |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Jon | 06/12/2023 09:00:15 a.m. | 06/12/203 6:35:37 p.m. | 06/13/2023 09:01:14 a.m. | 06/13/2023 04:15:37 p.m. | 06/24/2023 11:00:00 a.m. | 06/24/2023 7:00:15 p.m. |  |  |  |  |

The number of clocks ins and clock out can go all the way across an Excel spreadsheet, so, there could be hundreds of columns per Name.

How can I calculate all the Out vs. In timestamps, and arrive a total # hours worked figure, by person?  In Excel, I can use sumproduct and sum up all the Outs, and then subtract all the Ins, and arrive at the correct answer.  However, it's incredibly slow when adding that formula to the spreadsheet, so I was hoping to import the data from Excel into a dataframe, and calculate the answer using Pandas.  However, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do it.

Any suggestions or assistance would be GREATLY appreciated.

Thanks!,

Clare

Answer (score 2, accepted):

many typos in your example. so i fix it

**Example Code**

```
nan = float('nan')
data1 = {'Name': {0: 'Tom', 1: 'Steve', 2: 'Jon'},
 'In': {0: '06/12/2023 12:05:00 p.m.',
  1: '06/12/2023 1:00:00 p.m.',
  2: '06/12/2023 09:00:15 a.m.'},
 'Out': {0: '06/12/2023 12:15:00 p.m.',
  1: '06/12/2023 5:00:00 p.m.',
  2: '06/12/2023 6:35:37 p.m.'},
 'In.1': {0: nan,
  1: '06/13/2023 09:00:00 a.m.',
  2: '06/13/2023 09:01:14 a.m.'},
 'Out.1': {0: nan,
  1: '06/13/2023 5:00:00 p.m.',
  2: '06/13/2023 04:15:37 p.m.'},
 'In.2': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: '06/24/2023 11:00:00 a.m.'},
 'Out.2': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: '06/24/2023 7:00:15 p.m.'},
 'In.3': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan},
 'Out.3': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan},
 'In.4': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan},
 'Out.4': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

**Step1**

make in and out series and convert to datetime

```
s = pd.to_datetime(df.set_index('Name').rename(columns=lambda x: x.split('.')[0]).stack())
```

`s`

```
Name      
Tom    In    2023-06-12 12:05:00
       Out   2023-06-12 12:15:00
Steve  In    2023-06-12 13:00:00
       Out   2023-06-12 17:00:00
       In    2023-06-13 09:00:00
       Out   2023-06-13 17:00:00
Jon    In    2023-06-12 09:00:15
       Out   2023-06-12 18:35:37
       In    2023-06-13 09:01:14
       Out   2023-06-13 16:15:37
       In    2023-06-24 11:00:00
       Out   2023-06-24 19:00:15
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

**Step2**

calculate sum of difference of in and out

```
s.diff().xs('Out', level=1).groupby(level=0, sort=False).sum()
```

output:

```
Name
Tom     0 days 00:10:00
Steve   0 days 12:00:00
Jon     1 days 00:50:00
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: Hi Panda Kim,  Wow!  I'm SO glad I posted on here asking for advice.  Your answer did EXACTLY what I needed, in two lines of code.  You have no idea how much that has helped me.  Thank you so very much.  I am truly grateful to you.